# Oracle sql make strings inside single qoutes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

What I wanted is to place every string inside single qoutes even if it is delimited by a dot something like this:

**Input:** Hi.Hello.World

**Output:** 'Hi'.'Hello'.'World'

***Note:*** Inputs can be 2 or more words delimited by a dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT '''' || REPLACE(string, '.', '''.''') || ''''
FROM yourTable
```

### Demo

The idea here is we replace every dot `.` with dot in single quotes `'.'`.  This covers all internal dots/quotes.  Then, to handle the outside single quotes, we can concatenate them on both sides.

Comment: thanks @Tim. this solved my problem! it also makes a string without dot inside single qoutes which I also needed but I forgot to include in my question. :D